# typescript generic get typeof dynamic nested key

Tags: typescript

I have a generic type, and I want to get typings for the nested key to be typed correctly. Is it achievable, right now it does not work

```
export type Config = {
  [K: string]: {
    [M: string]: {
      options: string[];
      type?: 'checkbox' | 'toggle';
    };
  };
};

export interface FiltersProps<T extends Config, M extends keyof T, X extends keyof M> {
  config: T;
  values: {
    [K in M]: string[];
  };
}
```

Example:

```
const config = {
  statuses: {
    done: {},
    expired: {},
  },
};

const filterProps = {
  config,
  values: {
    done: [], <-- correctly typed
    expired: [], <-- correctly typed
  },
};
```

how do i get correct typings for keys in `values` ??

Comment: in the `FiltersProps` you have a type of `string[]` but in the `filterProps` they are objects. What should be the type of the `values` field?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out), but it does not really change the point, i am curious is there a way to extract the nested object key names from config into keys of `values` ?

Comment: my question is what do you exactly want `values` to be? Just a flat array of nested keys?

Comment: values should be an object with keys that correspond to the nested keys of `Config`

Comment: @Sam Please, populate objects `config.statuses.done`, `config.statuses.expired`, `filterProps.values.done`, and `filterProps.values.expired` with some values. That will help understand the desired algorithm.

Comment: it seems like im didnt make my self clear)), it does not matter what the property values of  the `value` object should be, I just want the NAMES of the keys of `values` to be same as the nested key NAMES of `Config`, i hope i made it a little more clear)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1aEAw) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: seems like its working) thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the *mapped type* a bit. You typed `X` incorrectly, it should be `keyof T[M]` not, `keyof M`, since `M` will be some key, which is typed as `number | string | symbol`.

```
interface FiltersProps<T extends Config, M extends keyof T = keyof T> {
  config: T;
  values: {
    [K in keyof T[M]]: string[];
  };
}
```

Testing:

```
const filterProps: FiltersProps<typeof config> = {
  config,
  values: {
    done: [],
    expired: [],
  },
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2AzAlgczgF44BvAWACg44BtAaQC44BnGKXTfAXWYupp0AsszYcuvMlUGCIYGLiwtR7TvlrcA3NJkJkwAPzMA5AGMAFsFMBrAEYQQxuAB84xmBHz4ANsGPaBGgBfAOCAkKoqUEhYOE4YYChsAENTVAAxXG8EqBYABSg5FgAeABU4UATMABMWdCw8fAAaOCEKkCrauGtgRAhsOHKSHr6B0oA+KQFTBoJmUtC4ADdk7wBXYGUpmQY4zG7e-sHaIW5JMTUNRYjKIMjKGcw2OEfG4m3WGGSYNZZNvh0NGqWGAAMCsnkiiezA0TUBcCCcPB0VwUGA1TBujgcgUShh3CRMkROmJtwCVEezzw2USBSKzEyNNydLAJSQKCOrwIkxI-BoXOaOhW63+HyBIPxhMEKLRGLoBJJSJuQA)

Comment: Oh, no, I've posted the same answer just one minute later :) I'm gonna delete mine :)

Comment: [Tweaked example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2AzAlgczgF44BvAWACg44BtAaQC44BnGKXTfAXWYupp0AsszYcuvMlUGCIYGLiwtR7TvlrcA3NJkJkwAPzMA5AGMAFsFMBrAEYQQxuAB84xmBHz4ANsGPaBGgBfAOCAkKoqUEhYOE4YYChsAENTVAAxXG8EqBYABSg5FgAeABU4UATMABMWdCw8fAAaOCEKkCrauGtgRAhsOHKSHr6B0oA+KQFTBoJmUtC4ADdk7wBXYGUpmQY4zG7e-sHaIW5JMTUNRYjKIMjKGcw2OEfG4m3WGGSYNZZNvh0NGqWGAAMCsnkiiezA0TUBcCCcPB0VwUGA1TBujgcgUShh3CRMkROmJAks3m8EExglsiFBHxkOKhW1h8NJwSoNyoj2eeGyiQKRWYmX5uUFYBKSBQR1eBEmJH4NFlzR0K3W-wZcGBmHprOR4FR6PxhMEAHpTXBabqCSSkTcgA)

Comment: is the above possible?

Comment: @Sam try [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgKDBw)